# White and back to tandem breaker. Is this correct?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I opened up a sub panel to find the breaker wired with a 14/2 neutral going to tandem breaker.  Is this correct?  Why would they have wired the circuit this way?

[image]

Comment: It could be. We need to see the other half of the circuits.

Answer (score 2):

If it powering the same device(like a hot water heater), it is correct.

It is using the white wire for the second hot/live wire on a 240 volt device.

The white wire should have black tape/paint on it at both ends to mark it as a hot wire(not a neutral wire).

Comment: I’ll have to check.  I don’t think I have any 15 amp 220v appliances.  Thanks

Comment: Then you might have a problem.  Maybe someone just got high and switched black and white, which needs to be changed.  Add a picture of the whole panel to your question.

Comment: I figured it out.  Was for an old driveway heater.  Thank you

Comment: You should clarify that by "it", you just mean the use of a white wire there. There's a lot of things in that picture that definitely aren't correct, like using a piece of copper wire in place of an approved handle tie.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Prior to 2005 the NEC only specified "approved handle ties", which "approved" was defined in Article 100 as "acceptable to the authority having jurisdiction."

Answer (score 2):

Notice the handle tie.

someone took 2 tandem breakers and turned the center one into a Double pole.

You can purchase them and they are called a quad.

I can not read the breaker values but it could be a 1520, 2015 and the center is for a well pump or 2020 2020 as an example this would be actually legal IF the panel is listed for tandems and it had a factory handle tie.

The reason I mention well pump is that looks like a 2 slot panel that someone created 2 extra circuits.

As far as the white wire on a “hot” from the age of the panel just about all 240v small branch circuits were run like this.

I missed the 14-2 so it could be 1515 1515

Comment: Blue handle = 15A.  Bryant used the same color code as Bussman fuses.

Comment: Isn't this a triplex rather than a quad, since only the inside handles are tied together, and not the outside ones?

Comment: @ Joseph , Nope there are 2 tandems or 4 breakers in 2 full sized slots or a quad, some mfg’s handle tie both pairs inside and or outsides.